# Why System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.GetPattern() method does not use Generics?

Tags: wpf, generics, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

The [GetPattern()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer.getpattern.aspx) method implementation of `WPF UI Automation system` is implemented taking the enum parameter `PatternInterface` and we normally use it in the following way:

```
//Code with original implementation
ButtonAutomationPeer buttonPeer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button1);
IInvokeProvider provider = (IInvokeProvider)buttonPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke); //Line in Question
//To invoke the click event of button we then use the following code:
provider.Invoke();
```

From the above code, it seems that the line with comment **Line in Question** is not strongly typed, we need to cast the return from `GetPattern()` method to the required interface and then use it to invoke the specific UI automations.

**Question is:**
Would it not have been better if the implementation of the `GetPattern()` method in `WPF` was done using already present `Generics` in .Net Framework as below:

```
public T GetPattern<T>;
```

- where, I would then pass the required interface pattern name while
  calling the `GetPattern<T>` method and get that interface instance
  strongly typed and would also ***not*** need a ***cast***. What
  thought has Microsoft given in the original implementation of
  `GetPattern()` method requiring an `enum`?
- Would using enums in the method parameters not break the
  maintainability of the `GetPattern()` original implementation. I
  would say that when a new Control interface pattern is needed to be
  supported, that *pattern interface's* enum value would need to be
  added to the enum parameter named `PatternInterface`

I suppose it is easier and better to call the method and get the interface pattern using the below new code that uses calling the Generic implementation:

```
//Code with New Generics based implementation
ButtonAutomationPeer buttonPeer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button1);
IInvokeProvider provider = buttonPeer.GetPattern<IInvokeProvider>(); //Line in Question
//To invoke the click event of button we then use the following code:
provider.Invoke();
```

Comment: We can't tell you why Microsoft made a certain design decision - You should ask on the appropriate forum and see if you get a reply

Comment: @Basic in case you can't tell it, keep away from the question and dont vote to close it, because there are many other people on this site who might very well know the answer to the question and have more suggestions as well in terms of the pros and cons of the implementation, and this question is not asking why Microsoft had implemented this way; rather it asks whether another way to present the method would have benefited the programming world and how..

Comment: @CSharpVJ If someone can exactly answer your question then that will be great, but in case you don't get an answer or question is closed, then I would suggest you to post this idea on [MS Coneect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), that is the only place you can get a good answer to this question.

Comment: This is another example of people being far too keen to close questions. I think it's a perfectly good question. I wish people would stop being holier-than-thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for the usual reason: they didn't have a time machine.  Visible from the "History" annotations in the source code files available from the Reference Source, work on the UI Automation classes started around June 2003 with evidence that it got derived from earlier work.  Generics didn't become available until 2005.

From dd/wpf/src/UIAutomation/UIAutomationTypes/System/Windows/AutomationPattern.cs:

```
// History:
//  06/02/2003 : BrendanM Ported to WCP
```

Which was very likely Brendan McKeon.  No decent guess at what "WCP" might have meant.

Comment: I suppose then this API's signature can't be changed now, doing that will cause a compatibility issue (or can it be changed?)..And this may be largely becoz this feature may not have been tested much and code reviewed much..